# xamarin.forms android - linear layout not presented as expected

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, android-linearlayout

I have this code for custom keyboard.

Its xamarin.forms for android.

I want the keyboard to be presented from bottom of the page and to raise the Entry if needed.

the result is that the keyboard is presented on top of the page and covers the entry if the entry is on the top.

~

```
public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
            return;

        Android.InputMethodServices.Keyboard numericKeyboard = new Android.InputMethodServices.Keyboard(Control.Context, Resource.Xml.keyboard2);
        CustomKeyboardView numericKeyboardView = new CustomKeyboardView(Control.Context, null);
        numericKeyboardView.Id = Control.Id;
        numericKeyboardView.Keyboard = numericKeyboard;
        numericKeyboardView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        numericKeyboardView.PreviewEnabled = false;

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // THIS IS THE LAYOUT CREATION
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent); // maybe WrapContent on all
        lp.Gravity = GravityFlags.Bottom;
        lp.BottomMargin = 0;

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////

        Activity activity = this.Context as Activity;

        activity.AddContentView(numericKeyboardView, lp);

        Control.Touch += (sender, ex2) => 
        {
            if (numericKeyboardView.Visibility == ViewStates.Gone)
            {
                //Xamarin.Forms.Animation animation = Android.Views.Animations.AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(
                Android.Views.Animations.Animation animation = Android.Views.Animations.AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(
                this.Context,
                    Resource.Animation.slide_in_bottom
                );
                numericKeyboardView.ShowWithAnimation(animation);
                numericKeyboardView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }

            ex2.Handled = true;
        };                       
    }
}
```

~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the keyboard to be presented from bottom of the page and to raise the Entry if needed.

You need to wrap your `numericKeyboardView` with a [`RelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) and set the Rule of [`AlignParentBottom`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM).

In `OnElementChanged` method, add the following codes:

```
//Create RelativeLayout for Keyboard
Android.Widget.RelativeLayout rl = new Android.Widget.RelativeLayout(this.Context);
//Create the LayoutParams for Keyboard
Android.Widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new Android.Widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FillParent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);
//set the AlignParentBottom rule
rlp.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentBottom);
//set the LayoutParams to Keyboard
numericKeyboardView.LayoutParameters = rlp;
//add the keyboard to RelativeLayout
rl.AddView(numericKeyboardView);
//get current activity
Activity activity = this.Context as Activity;
//Add the Layout View to activity
activity.AddContentView(rl,rlp);
```